# Filter Operator API response not working in RxSwift

Tags: ios, swift, api, rxjs, rx-swift

I am not able to find out the what is the issue , just to filter out response based on status code as follow:

The code should be filter out the response based on the status code & return `response & data` as observable.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few issues with your approach:

- Why are you using `Observable.create` when you have `URLSession.shared.rx.response` that is already returning `Observable`?
- Your last `flatMap` should return an `Observable` but you are not returning anything from there
- There's `URLSession.shared.rx.data` that does the `statusCode` check for you
- You can use `.decode` operator for decoding
- Why it's a generic func that returns `T` but is named `getUsers`?
- You are never subscribing to the inner `Observable` inside `Observable.create` so your reactive chain will never run

Given these issue you can adapt your code to:

```swift
func getUsers<T: Codable>(urlStr: String) -> Observable<T> {
  guard let url = URL(string: urlStr) else { return .empty() } 
  return URLSession.shared.rx.data(request: .init(url: url))
    .decode(type: T.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
}
```